# Constraint generic type to be a subclass of another generic type in the same method

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the following method signature:

```
func someMethod<U: AnyObject, T: AnyObject>(_ firstClassType: U.Type?, and secondClassType: T.Type) where U: T {
    // Do something here
}
```

This yields the following error:

> Type 'U' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'T'

Is there a way to constrain `U` to be `T` or a subclass of `T`?

If I modify the following method to this:

```
func someMethod<T: AnyObject>(_ firstClassType: T.Type?, and secondClassType: T.Type) {
    // Do something here
}
```

I get this error when calling the method like this:

```
someMethod(MySubclass.self, and: MyClass.self)
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'MySubclass.Type' to expected argument type '_.Type?'

The error goes away and everything seems ok if I use the first case of the method signature but remove the `where U: T` constraint. But that also means that I can call the method with 2 unrelated types which is something I would like to prevent.

So, am I missing something or is this something that I can't do in Swift?

Comment: As explained in my answer for the linked duplicate, this is a known limitation of the Swift compiler at the moment. What you are looking for is not possible currently.

Comment: Damn! I did search for it around here but I guess I've missed that. I'll take a look, thanks @Dávid Pászto!